# How to turn the Web of Science advanced query into regular expression in R?

Tags: r, regex, string, text, stringr

To do advanced search in Web of Science, we could use query like:

```
TI = ("ecology" AND ("climate change" OR "biodiversity"))
```

This means we want to extract papers with titles containing "ecology" and ("climate change" or "biodiversity"). The according regular expression would be(here TI is a string vector of titles):

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(TI,"ecology") & str_detect(TI,"climate change|biodiversity")
```

Is there any way to get the regular expression from the WoS query?

Comment: What is a WoS query ? Do I need some package to run this? When I run `TI = ("ecology" AND ("climate change" OR "biodiversity"))` in R console I get `Error: unexpected symbol in "TI = ("ecology" AND"`

Comment: What do you want to do? Analyzing results downlaoded from WoS in R? Trying to access WoS directly from R?

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Firstly we need to define the question more precisely.  We assume that a WoS query is a character string containing AND, OR, NOT, parentheses and fixed character strings in lower case or mixed case possibly surrounded by double quotes (this excludes upper case AND or OR appearing within double quotes unless part of a longer string).  We assume that we wish to generate a character string holding an R statement containing `str_detect` instances such as that shown in the question but not necessarily identical to the example shown as long as it satisfies the above.

For AND, OR and NOT we just replace them with the operators `&`, `|` and `& !`.  We then replace each instance of a word character followed by spaces followed by word character with the same except the spaces are replaced with an underscore.  We then replace any string of word characters that is not quoted with that string surrounded by quotes and finally we revert the underscores to spaces.

If `s` is the resulting string then `eval(parse(text = s)[[1]])` could be used to evaluate it against `target`.

`wos2stmt` does not use any packages but the generated statement depends on stringr due to the use of `str_detect` for consistency with the question.

```
wos2stmt <- function(TI, target = "target") {
    TI |>
      gsub(pattern = "\\bNOT\\b", replacement = "& !") |>
      gsub(pattern = "\\bAND\\b", replacement = "&") |>
      gsub(pattern = "\\bOR\\b", replacement = "|") |>
      gsub(pattern = "(\\w) +(\\w)", replacement = "\\1_\\2") |>
      gsub(pattern = '(?<!")\\b(\\w+)\\b(?!")', replacement = '"\\1"', perl = TRUE) |>
      gsub(pattern = "_", replacement = " ") |>
      gsub(pattern = '("[^"]+")', replacement = sprintf("str_detect(%s, \\1)", target)) |>
      gsub(pattern = '"(\\w)', replacement = r"{"\\\\b\1}") |>
      gsub(pattern = '(\\w)"', replacement = r"{\1\\\\b"}")
}

# test    
TI <- '"ecology" AND ("climate change" OR "biodiversity")'
stmt <- wos2stmt(TI)
```

giving:

```
cat(stmt, "\n")
## [1] "str_detect(target, \"ecology\") & (str_detect(target, \"climate change\") | str_detect(target, \"biodiversity\"))"
```

**2)**  The question seems to refer to generating R statements with `str_detect` but the subject refers to generating regular expressions.  In the latter case we accept a WoS query and output a regular expression for use with `str_detect` like this.  I haven't tested this out much so you will need to do that to explore its limitations.

Note that unlike (1)
this addresses the original question which we defined as not including NOT and automatic quoting (they are not mentioned in the quesiton as requirements).

```
wos2rx <- function(TI) {
  TI |>
    gsub(pat = ' *\\bOR\\b *', repl = '|') |>  
    gsub(pat = ' *\\bAND\\b *', repl = '') |>  
    gsub(pat = ' *"([^"]+)" *', repl = '(?=.*\\1)')
}

# test
library(stringr)

TI <- '("ecology" AND ("climate change" OR "biodiversity"))'
rx <- wos2rx(TI)
str_detect("biodiversity ecology", rx)
## [1] TRUE
str_detect("climate change biodiversity", rx)
## [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in fact, I just want to turn WoS query to regular expression. This means I have a offline database and want to extract entries due to the WoS query. WoS could search by title, and I have a database with a column named as "title".

Comment: There is one more question to add on, if there is a NOT stament, is there any way to transfer (e.g.  TI <- '"ecology" AND ("climate change" OR "biodiversity") NOT carbon')?
Also, if the phrase is not in two or more words, sometimes the quotes are no there, like the "carbon" above.

Comment: This is easier to add in (1) so In (1) we have added NOT which we assume means `& !` and it now handled both quoted and unquoted strings, e.g. `wos2stmt("climate change NOT biodiversity")` outputs `"str_detect(target, \"climate change\") & ! str_detect(target, \"biodiversity\")"`

Comment: A small problem is, when I search "forest", I would not want "deforest" to come unless I specify as "*forest", perhaps we should add "\b" before and after each phrase?

Comment: Have added \b to (1).